# Assign values to members of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

My class

```
class student   
{
 public string studentid { get; set; }
 public string groupid { get; set; }//Group id
}
```

My List

```
List<student> pupils = new List<student>();
```

here I select students with no group ID.
I have assigned students with no group ID as ="00"

```
      var studentWithNogroupID = from student in pupils where student.groupid == "00" select student;
```

I have an integer which I'm gonna increase each time and convert to char and assign each student.

```
int groupid=001;
string grid = myInt.ToString(groupid);
```

Here I'm assigning each member with group id like this..

```
foreach(var student in studentsWithNoGroupId)
{
  student.groupid = "grid";
}
```

My problem is I have to assign three members to a group. 
In other words 3 members should have same group id.
And after each 3 members it should increase the group id which is like this to create a new group id.

```
 groupid+=1;
```

How to go three by three in for loop or can anyone provide me a solution to assign three students to a group.

Comment: student.groupid = groupid / 3 and then groupid++ would that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to group `student` objects in groups of 3 students each?

Comment: This *is* a duplicate but the best answer can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq . You can use the Batch operator in [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) to batch elements in batches of 3.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Yes groups of 3 students, But after each 3 students it should increase group id..

Comment: @sloth
Asked because I don't have proper knowledge in linq and querying. 
Please try to provide some code samples. i can't grab a single thing from batch listing

Comment: @user3572467 Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/142637) answer. It splits a list into a list of lists of three elements. Then you could simply use something like `forach(var grp in Split(studentsWithNoGroupId) { foreach(var std in grp) { std.groupid == groupid; } groupid+=1; } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [modulo operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) to determine every third member:

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentsWithNoGroupId.Count; i++)
{
  if((i % 3) == 0)
   groupid += 1;
  studentsWithNoGroupId.ElementAt(i).groupId = groupid;
}
```

Comment: It gives me this error. Cannot apply indexing with []to an expression of type'System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable'

Comment: I updated the answer to work for IEnumerable

Comment: See as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654209/how-to-access-index-in-ienumerator-object-in-c